# getResourceAsStream("abc.xml") returning null

Tags: java, xml, unit-testing

I am writing a unit test case like this,

```
 public class XMLUtilsTest {
  private static final String XML_FOR_TEST ="a/b/c/xml_utils_test.xml";


 @Before
 public void setup() {

 }

@Test
public void testGetElementValue() throws Exception {
  InputStream inputStream = readTestXML(XML_FOR_TEST);

  System.out.println("Input Stream: "+inputStream);
}

private InputStream readTestXML(String testXmlFile) {
//InputStream inputStream = XMLUtilsTest.class.getResourceAsStream(testXmlFile);
//InputStream inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(testXmlFile);
 InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(testXmlFile);
 return inputStream;
 }
}
```

While debugging, i observe that this.getClass().getClassLoader() call in the readTestXML method loads class properly but when getResourceAsStream(testXmlFile) is invoked on output of this.getClass().getClassLoader() , the output is null.

my project structure is like this,

```
 --src
   --main
   --test
       --java
           --XMLUtilsTest.java
       --resources
           --a.b.c
               --xml_utils_test.xml
```

Please suggest.

Thanks,

Vijay Bhore

Comment: Try 'a.b.c/xml_utils_test.xml' if a.b.c are not directories.

Comment: @Martin: a.b.c is a package which translates to a/b/c path in filesystem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238048/junit-getresourceasstream-returning-null?rq=1

Comment: `XML_FOR_TEST ="/a/b/c/xml_utils_test.xml"` -- note leading slash

Comment: This was not conclusive for me. I replaced the xml file with a tried and tested xml in my project. The same code fragment worked. Sorry people.

Comment: I'm glad it's working. Cya! :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working. All you need to do is to check if src/test/resources is on your **classpath** and you should be fine (*Project properties -> java build path*)

I just recreated your scenario and it worked fine.

```
//Both snippets should work (don't forget to prepend a slash if using getClass().getResourceAsStream)
System.out.println(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("a/b/c/file.txt"));
System.out.println(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/a/b/c/file.txt"));
```