# How do I make my JUnit tests access resources from main?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit

I'm using the following call to get a stream so that I can find the filenames of some of my resources.

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(...)
```

This works fine when I run my code normally, and it also works fine if I duplicate my resources into my test folder.

How do I avoid this duplication and make my tests (when run through IDEA) use the resources from main?

Comment: I found a maven specific workaround. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6541151/451518

Comment: @defaultlocale Thanks. I'm not sure I understand that comment though. And I've updated the question to make it clear that I just want to run the tests normally through IntelliJ IDEA. (Though I will also want them to work with Maven later I guess.)

Answer (score 7):

Everything you have in `src/test/resources` is copied by [maven-resources-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) into `target/test-classes`. Then, everything you have in `src/main/resources` goes into `target/classes`. Then, [maven-surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/components/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) [configures](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/configuring-classpath.html) classpath in this order: `target/test-classes` first and `target/classes` next.

Thanks to that, if your resource stays both in `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources`, its "test" version will be loaded in the unit test.

If it only exists in the `src/main/resources`, it will be available in the unit test, without any further actions.

If it exists in `src/test/resources` only, you will have an ability to access it only during unit testing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Yegor. Everything you say appears to be true and yet it's still not working for some reason. I might be missing something silly though, so I'll keep looking.

Comment: Came across this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923129/get-a-list-of-resources-from-classpath-directory/3923685#comment67155595_3923685. It seems that if there are class files in the test folder then it doesn't list the non-class files that I am interested in. If I put the non-class files in their own folder then it picks them up. Bit weird.